# Query not going deep enough?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore & Java.
I am trying to change multiple values by query and batch.

My DB

```
Kullanıcılar
-deneme@deneme.com
--Hayvanlar
---RandomId1
   "ozel", "E65"  //I WANNA UPDATE THIS (First))

---RandomId2
----Dogru
-----RandomId
------Acep
      "ozel", "E65" //AND THIS (Second)
```

My Code

```
CollectionReference cr = fs.collection("Kullanıcılar/" + deneme@deneme.com + "/Hayvanlar");

Query query = cr.whereEqualTo("ozel", "E65");

query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        WriteBatch batch = fs.batch();

                    for (DocumentSnapshot ds : task.getResult()) {
                        batch.update(ds.getReference(), "ozel", "E75");
                    }
                        batch.commit();
                }
            }
        });
```

When i run this codes my only first value updates.
I never reach to second value :/

Comment: what do you mean by chance? do mean read or update or write?

Comment: I want to update data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `batch.commit()` outside your for loop

Comment: Accept the answer if its working so that others can find solution if they're stuck in the same place

Comment: It did not chance the result.
If it works i will accept it with pleasure.